# Magento Product Import Using Magmi - Access Denied Connecting to Database

Tags: mysql, magento, csv, import, magmi

I just set up Magmi to perform a bulk product import from CSV, I've configured everything as per the user guide but keep getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost'
>   to database ''

I've created a db user specifically for this task and have tested access with this user, no problems. There is a similar issue posted on their Sourceforge support page but with no response.

This has to be something fundamental, a configuration issue.

Comment: I should point out that the username and database name have been removed here when I posted as I put them inside tags, they are configured correctly and do appear in the error message.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: How can I import products images for multi-store, may i know csv header columns

Answer (score 0):

I love Magmi importer. It have been a great gift for uploading products to Magento recently for me.

I prefer Magmi UnderstandingE version over developers version.
You can download both for free. UnderstandingE version from https://understandinge.com/product/magmi-installation-wizard/
and developers version from https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git

Developer version of magmi can consist of bugs, which are not supposed to be fixed by general users.

Magmi stores user credential for database connectivity to Magento data base in file called magmi.ini located at magmi\conf. Have a look if they are correct for connecting to your Magento database.

If you are using UnderstandingE version it should work without error, whereas developer version need to be configured as per the downloaded copy.